# Can I use argmin in a set definition?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

If I have a set $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ and some $t\in \mathbb{R}^n$, how should I write "all vectors $s \in S$ such that the magnitude of their sum $s+t$ is minimal"?

My attempt is: $$\{s \in S \mid \underset{s}{\mathrm{argmin}}(|s+t|)\}$$ but it doesn't really seem right to me.

**EDIT:**

I had originally posed this question in terms of natural numbers to make it simpler, but failed to realise this meant there was only ever one unique solution..

Another attempt:$$\{s\in S : |s+t| \le |u+t|, \forall u \in S\}$$does this work?

Comment: This is certainly non-standard (the condition past the $|$ should be a predicate of $s$, whereas you just have a set, using $s$ as a dummy variable), but I'm a little confused as to what you want. Is $t$ a fixed integer? If so, then aren't you just looking for the singleton set $\{t + \min S\}$?

Comment: If $S\subseteq\Bbb N$, and $t$ is a fixed element of $\Bbb N$, then there is just one $s\in S$ such that $s+t$ is minimal among all such sums, and it is $\min S$.

Comment: Yes, sorry, i was trying to simplify my problem to make it easier to pose, but i just realised that that would mean there is only a single unique answer.. my application is actually using vectors.. i will update my question..

Comment: @user837206 : are you saying that $\mathrm{argmin}$ produces a set instead of a single value, so i could just write $\underset{s\in S}{\mathrm{argmin}}(|s+t|)$ for what i want to say?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: okay, thanks that is good to know for the future. If you want to make an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set builder notation is supposed to go something like this:
$$\{s \in S \mid P(s)\},$$
where $P(s)$ is a predicate, i.e. a true or false statement depending on $s$ (e.g. $s^\top \mathbf{1} = 0$). What you have written doesn't fit this mould. The expression $\underset{s}{\mathrm{argmin}}(|s+t|)$ refers to a set, not a true/false statement. If you are looking for the set of vectors $s \in S$ which minimise the expression $|s + t|$, then you actually want,
$$\underset{s \in S}{\mathrm{argmin}}(|s+t|).$$
The point of argmin is to return the set of minimising vectors $s$, whereas min returns the minimal numeric value of $|s + t|$ (i.e. it will be a non-negative real number, not a scalar).

Comment: thanks, is the 2nd attempt I made at defining the set also valid?

Comment: @GusKenny Yes, that's fine too.